# Oracle Data Modeler Define Primary Key

Tags: database, oracle, erd, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I am working on creating an ERD thru Oracle Data Modeler. Unfortunately, within the database the primary keys are not defined as a constraint, rather an index is set up on the primary key. I think this is why Oracle can't detect the primary keys and set them automatically. I didn't set up the database and can't make any changes.

Is there an easier way to have Oracle pull in the primary key from the index as opposed to going thru and defining each tables primary key? There are over a hundred tables within the database.

Thanks!

Comment: Whoever created your tables made a big mistake by not creating primary keys on each and every table.

Comment: @GriffeyDog yeah, unfortunately I can't do much about it.